# AjaxControlToolKit image appear as html tag in email message

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, email, send

I have used the AjaxControlToolKit as some sort of a WYSWYG editor to create email message.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to allow people to use the editor to add in images and send the final product (in HTML form) as email. The image of the email is stored on the server. The email message received should be something like normal marketing email with images and text.

The problem now is that text being formatted in the editor shows up correctly in the receiver's email client but the image displays as `<img src=....`. The path of the image is correct and the image did show up at the editor before leaving the editor screen.

The emails tested are Hotmail(did not prompt to allow things images), Gmail and MS Outlook.

Comment: Are you using an absolute or relative link for the image? Because a relative will not work in an email. Could you post the code you use to generate the image HTML?

Comment: I did use absolute link. I think I have roughly found out the problem. When I force the submitted message (one with the formatted text and image) back into the ajax editor I can see that the HTML code of the formatted text is correct but the HTML of the image is wrong.  Instead of <img src = "http://www.....panda.jpg"> I have &lt;img src = "http://www.....panda.jpg"&gt;    Anyone knows how to disable this automatic bracelet feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. It's very crude and inelegant.

```
txtDaMessage.Text = txtDaMessage.Text.Replace("&lt ;", "<");
txtDaMessage.Text = txtDaMessage.Text.Replace("&gt ;", ">");
```

The logic is since the `AjaxControlToolKit` wants to automatically convert my `'<'` and `'>'` of my html image tag to `"&lt ;"` and `"&gt ;"` respectively, I will force them back to the original form using the replace method.